# How to connect jquery autocomplete combobox to PHP mysql datasource

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I need connect my **jquery autocomplete** combobox to following datasource.i need to populate data combobox each time a letter is pressesd.

```
  if( isset( $_POST['catogery'] ) ) {   
      include('../DBConnection.php');
      $cat=$_POST['catogery']; 
      header('Content-type: application/json');  
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT SUBJECTCODE  FROM subjectmaster WHERE CATCODE = '$cat'"); 
      $return_arr = array(); 
      while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
          $row_array['id']=$row[0];
          array_push( $return_arr, $row_array );
      }
     echo json_encode($return_arr);

function getclassno(cat){
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST", 
      url:"reg/data/data.php", 
      async: false,
      data:{
         catogery:cat 
      },
      success: function(data){
         $.each(data, function (i, elem) {
            $('#classno').append( new Option(elem.id) );
         });
      }         
   });
}
```

function get class no is to populate data with combobox.it works fine.but i need to search the items
dynamically from the data base according to the entered letter.where  should i change to do that thing.because i have more than 3000 data to load to the combobox.

Comment: please specify the problem you are facing...also sanitize the input from the user our current code is vulnerable to injection attacks

Comment: and where is the code that is trying to connect to this code

Comment: hello i edit the question.so please be kind enough of pay attention on that

Answer (score 1):

You must try `jquery ui autocomplete`

Here is docs http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

And the working demo is http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/remote.html

You need to create a page like `search.php` which will return an array like 
`[{"id":"Ciconia ciconia","label":"White Stork","value":"White Stork"}]`

Answer (score 0):

I think This is jquery auto complete cm

example

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Another example

http://test.cita.illinois.edu/aria/combobox/combobox2.php